# Unable to start pm2 via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pm2

on a **Windows** machine, I have setup a very simple pipeline in Jenkins that does the following:

1. clone a git repository,
2. install the packages,
3. run the app via "**pm2 start command**"

Below is the entire pipleline script :

```
node {
    stage('dev'){
git credentialsId: 'my-credentials', url: 'git@myurl.git'

bat 'npm install'

bat 'pm2 start src\\index.js --name myapp'

}
}
```

Everything works fine except running the **pm2** command. The output error says :

*'pm2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

However, I can easily run the exact same **PM2** command via CMD, I have tried putting the last line command into a **.bat** file and asked jenkins to execute it, and get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins couldn't access the `PM2` that was installed on the Windows machine globally that is due to the fact that Jenkin was running as the system (root) user while pm2 was running with the local user. I had to include `PM2` in the package.config file of the project and then call it from the node_module folder.

> `\node_modules\.bin\pm2 start src\\index.js --name myapp`